# Scheme limit on number of elements in a list

Tags: list, scheme, element

Is there a limit on number of elements in a list? I read a file with the following code

```
(define output_collector 
    (let ((p (open-input-file filename_collector)))
        (let f ((x (read p)))
            (if (eof-object? x)
                (begin
                (close-input-port p)
                '())
                (cons x (f (read p)))))))
```

and if in my file there are 168 lines such as this one

> 3600 20.4

then everything works fine, but if there are 1200 lines, then there is a problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific on "then there is a problem"?

Comment: Well I have a script for Ansys Fluent and Fluent just closes if there are too many lines.

Comment: No Scheme system that I know has a limit on the number of elements in a list, other than the constraint imposed by available memory.

Comment: "then there is a problem."  Show the error message.

Comment: What Scheme implementation do you use?

Comment: @leppie He said he is using Fluent.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to be more specific, but you are probably getting a stack overflow. To fix the problem you need to use an accumulator. The following should work:

```
(define output_collector 
  (let ((p (open-input-file filename_collector)))
    (let f ((x (read p)) (acc '()))
      (if (eof-object? x)
          (begin
            (close-input-port p)
            (reverse acc))
          (f (read p) (cons x acc))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume you have lines of one integer within 63 bits (embedded in pointer) and a floating point (two words) and that a cons uses 3 words (most uses 2) the total amount of space for 1200 lines would be `(* 1200 (* (+ 0 2 3) 8)) ;==> 48000 (Bytes)`. For an implementation that only uses pointers to everything would be about double that and it's still not scary large.

I have no problem whatsoever running your code with a file having 1200 lines of increasing integers and floats in Ikarus and DrRacket. `time` reports it used one millisecond to do this. You could try replacing your recursion with iteration like below just to be sure that it isn't a Stack overflow causing your problems, but to be honest I think you need to add more info about the specific error you are getting.

```
;; Iterative version. Just for kicks
(define output_collector 
  (with-input-from-file
   filename_collector
   (lambda ()
     (let f ((x (read))(acc '()))
       (if (eof-object? x)
           (reverse acc)
           (f (read) (cons x acc)))))))
```